# How do i open a number of xlsx files when I only know part of the filename in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, directory, find

I am using Matlab 2013b. I have a list of excel files in a directory and I want to open chosen ones within a loop to read out the data.
I only know the start of each of the file names however, not the ending. I have a vector of numbers that provide the identifying portion of the file's name (filenumber), and I want to loop through the excel files one by one, opening them and extracting the data, then closing them.
There are 500 files, each of the format: img_*****ff********.xlsx, where the first set of asterisks is my filenumber, while the second set of asterisks is unknown.

So far, I have tried listing what is in the directory using:

```
list=dir('E:\processed\Img*');
filenames={list.name}
```

This provides with with the full file names.
I tried then within a loop to create the part of the filename I know exists:

```
x = sprintf('Img_%d_FF_',img(1,1));
```

I then thought I could use 'Find' to look for my my partial filename/string in the 'filenames' structure above. I don't think I have the code correct for this datatype though:

```
index = find(strcmp({list.name}, x)==1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close, but the issue is that `strcmp` compares the *whole string* and since you only have the beginning part, it is not going to match. I would use [`strncmp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strncmp.html) to compare only the first `n` characters of the string. We can determine what `n` is based upon the length of your string `x`.

```
matches = strncmp({list.name}, x, numel(x));
thisfile = list(matches).name;
```